# city not display on map when assign values of longitude and latitude on ngOnInit Event?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7, angular-routing, angular-resource

**problem**

when assign values of latitude and longitude on ngOnInt event map city or area display Empty ?

I work on angular 7 .

when assign values of latitude and longitude on ngOnInit event map city or area display empty

According to latitude and longitude city must display is New York but it display empty .

How to solve problem ?

what I try below :

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  title = 'angular-gmap';
  @ViewChild('mapContainer', { static: false }) gmap: ElementRef;
  map: google.maps.Map;
 lat = 0;
 lng = 0;

  coordinates = new google.maps.LatLng(this.lat, this.lng);

  mapOptions: google.maps.MapOptions = {
    center: this.coordinates,
    zoom: 8
  };

  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: this.coordinates,
    map: this.map,
    title: 'Hello World!'
  });
  ngOnInit() {
   this. lat = 40.73061;
    this.lng = -73.935242;

  }
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.mapInitializer();
  }

  mapInitializer() {
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.gmap.nativeElement, this.mapOptions);
    this.marker.setMap(this.map);
  }
}
```

Image display that map not display city

[image: map place not display]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create the `coordinates` and the `mapOptions` **before** setting `lat` and `lng` in ngOnInit. So the coordinates have the initial values of lat and lng: 0 and 0.

Your code can be reduced to

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  title = 'angular-gmap';
  @ViewChild('mapContainer', { static: false }) gmap: ElementRef;

  // no need for instance fields that no one uses

  // no need for ngOnInit

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.mapInitializer();
  }

  mapInitializer() {
    // the coordinates are created with the correct lat and lng. Not with 0, 0
    const coordinates = new google.maps.LatLng(40.73061, -73.935242);

    const mapOptions: google.maps.MapOptions = {
      center: coordinates,
      zoom: 8
    };

    const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: coordinates,
      title: 'Hello World!'
    });

    const map = new google.maps.Map(this.gmap.nativeElement, mapOptions);
    marker.setMap(map);
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for reply but how to assign values of latitude and longtude on ngonint event

Comment: Why do you think you need to do that in ngOnInit? Why do you even have all these instance fields? Doyou use them in the template? Anyway, if you really want to initialize them in ngOnInit for whatever obscure reason, then also initialize everything that depends on them in ngOnInit: coordinates, mapOptions, marker.

Comment: To make you understand, here's basically what you're doing: `const a = 0; console.log(a); a = 40;` This will print 0, not 40.

Comment: suppose i get value of two variables lat and lng from service in angular can i assign values outside ngonint or not

Comment: yes. But what you need to understand is that 1. these don't need to be stored in instance fields if the template doesnt need them; 2. you can only contain the mapOptions and the marker, which contain the lat and the lng, once they have their correct values. If you create them before, then mapOptions and marker will have 0, 0. Does that make sense?

Comment: can you show me that by code i cannot get sense or give me more details if possible